# C pre-processor define/macro

Tags: macros

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to do what I'm trying to accomplish with defines. I'm essentially trying to create 2 sets of definitions of a parameter (in the example below I used height), that I can access via an index. However this index may change, but the parameter should still be accessible.

```
#define INDEX_M      0
#define INDEX_Y      1

#define HEIGHT_MALE    60
#define HEIGHT_FEMALE  50

#define HEIGHT_##INDEX_M   HEIGHT_MALE
#define HEIGHT_##INDEX_F   HEIGHT_FEMALE
```

Would be used as such:

```
for (int i = 0; i < database_size; i++){
    printf("Height requirement for person %d is: %d", i, HEIGHT_(person[i].gender));
}
```

This way, we can change the index of male/female to match the database's definition and still have this code work.

I've tried using a macro, but the issue I'm running into is that it wont let me use the ## notation on the first half of the define.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up coming with this:

```
#define __HEIGHT_(X) ((X == INDEX_M) ? HEIGHT_MALE : (X == INDEX_M) ? HEIGHT_FEMALE : 0)
```

Now I can call something like this:

```
printf("%d", __HEIGHT(INDEX_M));
> 60
```

This seems to be producing the results I wanted. Is there something I'm missing?

EDIT: Improved to be generic as follows:

```
#define ATTRIBUTE_GET(param, gender)((gender == INDEX_M) ? param ##_MALE : (gender == INDEX_F) ? param ##_FEMALE : 0)
```

Used as:

```
printf("%d", ATTRIBUTE_GET(HEIGHT, INDEX_M));
```

Comment: Note that variable names containing two consecutive underscores are reserved (for compiler stuff, I believe), so using `__HEIGHT_<whatever>` was potentially dangerous anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No. This cannot work. You are mixing compile-time (#define) and run-time (expression evaluation) features.